# Wrap text in the document inside custom command

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I have created a custom command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\projectSubheading}[3]{
%  \vspace{-1pt}
  \item
    \begin{tabular*}{0.97\textwidth}[t]{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
      \textbf{#1} & #2 \\
      \textit{\small#3}
    \end{tabular*}
    %\vspace{-5pt}
}
```

I am passing 3 fields to the command

```
    \projectSubheading
          {Multipurpose Unmanned Autonomous Vehicle \href{https://github.com/}{\faGithub}{Arizona, US}
{Relevant Coursework: Artificial Intelligence, Data Structure and Algorithms, System Programming and Operating Systems, Computer Networks, Soft Computing, Digital Signal Processing}
```

The output does not fit on the page:

[image]

How can I wrap the text inside the command?

Comment: The tabular columns `l` and `r` do not break the text into lines. You can use the `p` column type with a fixed width instead or have a look at the `tabularx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no need to place the content inside a `tabular`-like environment. Instead, the following definition of `\projectSubheading` uses `\hfill` to spread the first two arguments, and sets the final argument as a separate paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref,fontawesome}

\newenvironment{projects}
  {\begin{itemize}}
  {\end{itemize}}

% \projectSubheading{<project>}{<location>}{<description>}
\newcommand{\projectSubheading}[3]{%
  \item
    \textbf{#1} \hfill #2 \par
    \itshape\small #3
}

\begin{document}

\begin{projects}

  \projectSubheading
    {Multipurpose Unmanned Autonomous Vehicle \href{https://github.com/}{\faGithub}}% Project
    {Arizona, US}% Location
    {Relevant Coursework: Artificial Intelligence, Data Structure and Algorithms, 
      System Programming and Operating Systems, Computer Networks, Soft Computing, Digital Signal Processing}% Description

\end{projects}

\end{document}
```